# Proxy change on runtime in Awesomium

Tags: vb.net, proxy, webbrowser-control, awesomium

I've read bunch of Q&As but none helped me.

I'm using VB.net; added awesomium browser control on the form. I need to be able to change its proxy server on the fly (example: User clicks a button to change proxy IP & port). Would it be possible? If not maybe I could create a dynamic awesomium browser control and than add it to the form (also on button click). But still don't know how to initialize control with the proxy.

If I cannot change it while running that is fine. Can I read proxy from some file and than initialize control with that proxy?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind - below worked for me:

```
Dim prefs As WebPreferences = New WebPreferences()
prefs.ProxyConfig = txtProxy.Text
Dim session As WebSession = WebCore.CreateWebSession(prefs)
Dim webcontrol As WebControl = New WebControl()
webcontrol.WebSession = session
Me.panWeb.Controls.Add(webcontrol)
webcontrol.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
webcontrol.Source = New Uri(txtURL.Text)
webcontrol.Visible = True
```